# Mongoose deep populate returning only ID not the entire Object/Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

This question has been asked to death over here, but doesn't seem like a clear cut answer is out there.

So I have a DB where a User has many Topics, Posts & Comments, A Topic has many posts, and a Post has many Comments.

The adding Users, Topics, Posts & Comments is working properly. The Topics are also being displayed with populating the posts inside it.(with minor redirection glitch). But I am unable to populate the Comments inside the posts. This is what I have so far.

Gettopic method inside the Topic Controller

```
  gettopic: function(req, res){
    console.log("get_topic query", req.body._id)
    Topic.findOne({_id: req.body._id}).populate('posts').populate('posts.comments').exec(function (err, topic) {
        if(err){
            console.log("Something went Wrong");
            res.json(err)
        }else{
            console.log(topic);
            res.json(topic);
        }
        })
    }
```

Topic Model

```
var TopicSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  topic: String,
  description: String,
  category: String,
  post_count: Number,
  user_name: String,
  _User: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
  posts: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post'}],
  created_at: Date
});
```

Post Model

```
var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  post: String,
  up_vote: Number,
  down_vote: Number,
  user_name: String,
  _User: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
  _Topic: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Topic'},
  comments: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment'}],
  created_at: Date
});
```

Comment Model

```
var CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  comment: String,
  user_name: String,
  _User: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
  _Post: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post'},
  created_at: Date
});
```

Find Topic.findOne is working properly even populating the "Posts", but when populating the comments, only the Ids show, have console.log in both back end and frontend.

[image: Chrome Console]

[image: Terminal]

As you can see it hasnt fully populated the arrays, can only see it as an [OBJECT] in the terminal and Id's in JS Console.

What am i doing wrong?

console.log(JSON.stringify(topic.posts,undefined,2))

```
{
  "_id": "56b3f865fe0aca747e9dae4f",
  "topic": "New topic in new DB",
  "description": "Testing Phase 1",
  "category": "HTML",
  "user_name": "Ani",
  "post_count": 0,
  "__v": 7,
  "posts": [
    {
      "_id": "56b3f880fe0aca747e9dae50",
      "post": "Posting Answer Phase 1",
      "user_name": "Ani",
      "up_vote": 0,
      "down_vote": 0,
      "created_at": "2016-02-05T01:18:56.709Z",
      "__v": 3,
      "comments": [
        "56b40368004a0707806e4b93",
        "56b4046beef00e4c82126269",
        "56b406656171e44383374cf0"
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "56b4061a51c0d3f282b89a95",
      "post": "Answer/Post V.2.0",
      "user_name": "Ani",
      "up_vote": 0,
      "down_vote": 0,
      "created_at": "2016-02-05T02:16:58.575Z",
      "__v": 1,
      "comments": [
        "56b4062551c0d3f282b89a96"
      ]
    }
```

console.log(JSON.stringify(topic,undefined,2))

```
"posts": [
    {
      "_id": "56b3f880fe0aca747e9dae50",
      "post": "Posting Answer Phase 1",
      "user_name": "Ani",
      "up_vote": 0,
      "down_vote": 0,
      "created_at": "2016-02-05T01:18:56.709Z",
      "__v": 3,
      "comments": [
        "56b40368004a0707806e4b93",
        "56b4046beef00e4c82126269",
        "56b406656171e44383374cf0"
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "56b4061a51c0d3f282b89a95",
      "post": "Answer/Post V.2.0",
      "user_name": "Ani",
      "up_vote": 0,
      "down_vote": 0,
      "created_at": "2016-02-05T02:16:58.575Z",
      "__v": 1,
      "comments": [
        "56b4062551c0d3f282b89a96"
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Please show the Object "text" and not screenshots. That is actually the reason why images are blocked from new posters under the required rep cap. To discourage posting of images when text is more appropriate.

Comment: There is no Object "text", in the Terminal all i am getting is [Objects] and in the browser console

comments: Array[3]
0: "56b40368004a0707806e4b93"
1: "56b4046beef00e4c82126269"
2: "56b406656171e44383374cf0"

Comment: tried to console.log topics.posts .. its prints the posts with the comments as an array but with only the Ids like before. 

console.log topics.posts.comments gives back undefined.

Comment: Basic serialization `console.log(JSON.stringify(topic,undefined,2))`. As stringification of the "Object" does not happen that deeply in logging by default. And what I mean by "text" is "paste" the "text" from the console. Not the screenshot.

Comment: have updated the main post. Wont be uploading images anymore . Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [mongoose-deep-populate](https://github.com/buunguyen/mongoose-deep-populate) plugin for deeply nested objects

```
var deepPopulate = require('mongoose-deep-populate');

Topic.findOne({
        _id: req.body._id
    }).deepPopulate('posts posts.comments').exec(function (err, topic) {
        if (err)
            res.json(err)
        else{
            console.log(topic);
            res.json(topic);
        };
    });
```